# Color "geom_density_ridges_gradient"

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

I would like to add a gradient colour such as the next plot :
[image]

Obtained from this web : https://wilkelab.org/ggridges/articles/introduction.html

This is the code that I am using :

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Prec, y= year)) + 
geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale=5, size = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c( option = "C")
```

but I am not getting the desire results, also tried other gradients such as:

```
scale_colour_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(10))
scale_colour_gradient(low = "white", high = "black")
scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", na.value = NA)
```

etc....

My database is huge with A tibble: 7,433 x 3
the year is a factor variable
Prec is a numeric variable
e.g.
year  Prec
1980   2
1981   3
1982   2.5
(etc..)
Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: You need to set an aesthetic fill variable - `aes(..., fill = variable_name)`

Comment: Mind sharing the df? Or part of it

Answer (score 0):

Note : `aes()` in `geom_density_ridges_gradient`

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Prec, y= year)) + 
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(aes(fill= ..x..), scale = 3, rel_min_height = 0.01, size=0.3) +
  scale_fill_gradientn( colours =  c("#0d0887FF", "#CC4678FF", "#F0F921FF"))
```